# Implement method of collection .add using only iterator

Tags: java, collections, iterator, addition, custom-collection

I must implement all methods of collection using iterator only.

My iterator:

```
class CustomIterator<T> implements Iterator {

        private int index;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < data.size();
        }
        @Override
        public T next() {
            return (T)data.get(index);
        }
        public void remove () {
            data.remove(index);
        }
    }
```

data, it is arraylist in my own collection.

For example, method size implement in my code:

```
public class CustomCollections<T> implements Collection {
public ArrayList<T> data;
 public int size() {
        CustomIterator iterator = new CustomIterator<>();
        int length= 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            length++;
        }
        return length;
    }
   }
```

But i don't know, how to implement method `.add`?

Please help me in that problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? This looks more like a custom collection than a custom iterator

Comment: that is true. i implement custom collection, using custom iterator. custom iterator i implemented. next, i want to implement custom collection.

Comment: Why not implement one of the collection interfaces? What is the type of "data"? Where is it defined?

Comment: data defined in my custom collection class

Comment: What makes you think this is possible?  None of the methods on your iterator let you add.